# Pandas | How to effectively filter a column

Tags: dataframe

I'm looking for a way to quickly and effectively filter through a dataframe column and remove values that don't meet a condition.

Say, I have a column with the numbers 4, 5 and 10. I want to filter the column and replace any numbers above 7 with 0. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about two separate things - filtering and value replacement. They both have uses and end up being similar in nature but for filtering I'll point to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071908/13059096).

Let's say our data frame is called `df` and looks like

```
   A   B
1  4   10
2  4   2
3  10   1
4  5   9
5  10  3
```

Column `A` fits your statement of a column only having values 4, 5, 10. If you wanted to replace numbers above 7 with 0, this would do it:

```py
df["A"] = [0 if x > 7 else x for x in df["A"]]
```

If you read through the right-hand side it cleanly explains what it is doing. It helps to include parentheses to separate out the "what to do" with the "what you're doing it over":

```py
df["A"] = [(0 if x > 7 else x) for x in df["A"]]
```

If you want to do a manipulation over multiple columns, then utilizing `zip` allows you to do it easily. For example, if you want the sum of columns `A` and `B` then:

```py
df["sum"] = [x[0] + x[1] for x in zip(df["A"], df["B"])]
```

**Take care when you overwrite data** - this removes information. It's a good practice to have the transformed data in other columns so you can trace back when something inevitably goes wonky.

Answer (score 0):

There is many options. One possibility for if then... is `np.where`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 200, 4, 5, 6, 11],
                'y': [4, 5, 10, 24, 4 , 3]})
df['y'] = np.where(df['y'] > 7, 0, df['y'])
```